# Rest API Integration Fees

Tags: rest-api, integration

I am starting to get setup with the REST API integration, and I am confused on how the billing works.

I read the following: 
"Salesforce charges 15% of net revenue. What does this imply? What is the fine print? Say i have 100 paid users and out of them only 20 use the salesforce integration. So 15% of 100 or 20?"

How exactly does this work when dealing with the customer..? And how does salesforce even know when I charge the customer?

Answer (score 1):

It's 15% of the licence fees involved. I'm guessing your app is OEM because of the way you've phrased this, so if you sell *n* licences for the Salesforce integration part it'll be 15% of *n*. If all users have access to the integration it'll be a charge for all of them.

If your app is just a client that people use with their own orgs, using OAuth to authenticate, then you're not liable for any costs as they're already paying for their licences.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Im still learning how the whole process works. How does salesforce know how much I am going to charge for each license and how much we are going to charge for initial set up fees?

Comment: I'm guessing the assumption is that you're selling through the AppExchange, in which case we see the transactions - see the [ISVforce Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/index_Left.htm) for much more.

Comment: If you're selling OEM and not via the AppExchange it's just up to you to report it, though before you get any great ideas about not doing so remember that the platform is forming a key component of your app, so being disingenuous about it would not benefit you in the long run.